# Map Scrollwheel to buttons?

Tags: mapping, keyboard-shortcuts, sendkeys

I want to make the mousewheel up and down send the <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> keys respectively - directly to the OS, as if it came from the keyboard. But only when the <kbd>Win</kbd> Key is pressed.

That is the Windows 7 Magnifier uses <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>  to zoom in and out, and I want to do that via win-mousewheel, the way it *should* have worked.  Any similar solution will do but would prefer to use the built-in one due to its great multi-monitor support.

I only know VB.NET and C# so in the likely scenario that the solution would be in another language please provide enough that I wouldn't need to learn the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.autohotkey.com/

Answer (score 2):

Example solution below. It works correctly with Win7 Magnifier, unfortuneatly needs Python 2.5.4, [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/pywin32-212.win32-py2.5.exe/download), [pyHook](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/files/) and [SendKeys](http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/). But it can be rewritten in C/C++ with only a little more effort.

```
import pythoncom, pyHook, SendKeys
IS_WIN_DOWN = False

def OnMouseEvent(event):
    if IS_WIN_DOWN:
        if event.Wheel == 1:
            SendKeys.SendKeys('{+}')
        else:
            SendKeys.SendKeys('-')
    return True

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    global IS_WIN_DOWNN
    if event.KeyID is 91: #LWIN == 91
        if event.Message == 256: #KEY_DOWN == 256
            IS_WIN_DOWN= True
        elif event.Message == 257: #KEY_UP == 257
            IS_WIN_DOWN= False
    return True

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.SubscribeMouseWheel(OnMouseEvent)
hm.SubscribeKeyDown(OnKeyboardEvent) 
hm.SubscribeKeyUp(OnKeyboardEvent) 
hm.HookMouse()
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Also: [old question with a solution in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746188/c-how-to-capture-global-mouse-hid-events)

Comment: oh durr that was my previous version on this question, forgot i wrote it!  Never did get a real answer on that one... thanks.